# Can I show execution cost when I call function every loop?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

I want to get execution cost every loop when function addData() was call. The solidity remix show execution cost when program run finish. How to show execution cost in each loop?

```
contract Test_loop {

    uint256 number;

    function testLoop() public{
        uint256 i=0;
        uint256 cnt=0;

        for(i;i<100;i++) {
            cnt++;
            
            addData(cnt);
            console.log(cnt);
        }
    }

    function addData(uint256 _number) public{
 
      number = _number;
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a tool for that. Besides Remix Hardhat support gas reporting 'out of the box'. Here is the command ```REPORT_GAS=true npx hardhat test```, but should also show you a total gas cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gasleft()`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) function to check how much gas is left after each operation. Subtracting this from the gas you had before the operation gives you the amount of gas used.

```
    function testLoop() public{
        for (uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            uint256 gasBefore = gasleft();
            addData(cnt);
            uint256 gasUsedForOperation = gasBefore - gasleft();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I never even saw that function before.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do anything remotely similar to that is to go to Remix `debugger` mode. There you can see the gas cost of each individual step.

However, that might be a bit too complex to do.

I myself usually take the end `gas_price` and **approximate** from that.

Example for your case:

```
gas_price = 89631 gas
basic_transaction_cost =  21000 gas
number of steps in the loop = 100

step_cost = (89631 - 21000)/100
step_cost = 686 gas
```